# how can i get finger print on run time in picture box using zkemkeeper library in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, fingerprint, zkemkeeper

hi I am working on an application developed in c# using zkemkeeper SDK and Machine is Zkteco TFT

everything is working fine and all events are working but I need to bypass device verification when someone swipes his finger I want to get a finger template and want to verify from database SQL.

i try this code but i got the error

`System.ArgumentNullException: 'Buffer cannot be null.Parameter name: buffer'`

```
Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        int dc = g.GetHdc().ToInt32();
        // zKFP.PrintImageAt(dc, 0, 0, zKFP.ImageWidth, zKFP.ImageHeight);

        object obj = null;

        zKFP.GetFingerImage(ref obj);
        byte[] data = (byte[])obj;

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
        Image imG = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Comment: Hi -- could you post some reproducible code to show us what you've tried and what specific problem, if any, you're getting in your code?

Comment: @mrblewog tell me bro i uploaded my code in my question, so how can i get my finger print on run time in picture box using zkemkeeper library ?

Answer (score -1):

`GetFingerPrint(ref obj)` is returning and object of type `System.Byte[]`.

Try this

```cs
axZKFPEngX1.GetFingerImage(ref obj); 
byte[] data = (byte[])obj; 
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data); 
Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```